# The unknown service dbus-:1.11-org.freedesktop.problems@0.service

Tags: fedora, d-bus, freedesktop

What is the weird service? From the logs it looks like it's a slice created by D-Bus at startup.

The January release of Fedora 35

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to add an excerpt of the log messages that alerted you to the existence of this service, and provide context when the messages about the service started appearing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2604301):

- `org.freedesktop.problems` is an interface for dbus on-demand service.
- When applications send signal to `org.freedesktop.problems`, a service defined in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.problems.service` would trigger, and will log messages in `/var/log/messages`